# xdotool only works in browser

Tags: ubuntu, keyboard-shortcuts, xdotool

I am trying to map a custom keyboard shortcut in Pop_OS! to issue some other keypresses, but I have gotten part of the way with `xdotool` but I still have some issues as it wont work in applications like discord, pycharm, webstorm and such, currently it only works in my terminal and browser.

What I am trying is to make a shortcut that will delete the current line of text I am on, by pressing something like <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Right Arrow</kbd>. Right now I have to press <kbd>End</kbd>, <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Home</kbd> and then <kbd>Delete</kbd>.

I have tried with `Xdotool` by first issuing this command in the terminal:

```
xdotool getactivewindow key End Shift+Home Delete
```

which seems to do what it is supposed to in the terminal and Firefox, but when I issue the shortcut in any other application nothing happens.

Btw Pop_OS! is built on Ubuntu so as far as I know, the way to add a custom keyboard shortcut should be identical.

Am I missing something in my `Xdotool` markup? From my understanding of the documentation it should work by using `getactivewindow`

Comment: If you visit some posts on xdotool tag, you will see it is not quite reliable. In my system, for example, `xdotool getactivewindow key slash` gives out a `q`.

Comment: Is there any other way to issue the keys with a command?

Comment: I'm not sure. Have a look at `pyautogui`.